# why looks my margin different in chrome as in all other browsers

Tags: html, css, margin

i have here a problem that i never seen before. i build a header with an menu icon on the left side and three icons on the right side of it. Two of the three icons on the right side, have badges. The problem is that the badges are looking perfect on safari, firefox, edge etc. but on chrome are they to much left.   if i change now the margin from `margin: 0 0 0 -8px` to `margin: 0 0 0 11px` is it looking good on chrome, but in all other browser is it to much right. How can it be that a margin looks different? Never seen it before.

```
.pulse-badge {
background: rgba(51,51,51, 0.87); ;
border-radius: 50%;
min-height: 1.3rem;
margin: 0 0 0 -8px;
position: absolute;
min-width: 1.3rem;
top: 0.8em;
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51,51,51, .051);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.33, 0, 1);}

@keyframes pulse {
    to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px transparent, 0 0 0 16px rgba(90, 153, 212, 0);
    }
}
```

thats the css of the badges and im using skeleton as framework. I also have here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/febg4cuo/1/) where ya can see it, if ya change the margin.  and here is a link with the live project if ya whant to see it with the other content if it helps [live](http://kallax.awesom-media.de/blank.html)

[image]
[image: chrome]

Comment: working fine for me..in all browsers

Comment: Sure ? I put two pics on the first comment, first one is firefox and the second chrome.

Update: We tested it on four different pc and one mac. Everywhere the same. Ony chrome makes the problems on all pc / macs

Comment: Try running it in incognito mode on Chrome and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Again, all looks fine here (Safari, Chrome on Mac, Chrome and Edge on PC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `right` than `margin:` then position your list to `relative`
Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/febg4cuo/3/

Edited:
you need to add position relative to your list

```
 .notification-bar> li{position:relative;}
```

Comment: Works, but now are both badges one above the other [Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/febg4cuo/5/)

Comment: did you see my fiddle?

Comment: i've seen it, but now are one above the other. i updated the live link so you can see it. i changed the .pulse-badge class, so i tooked it from your fiddle and than it looks like this

Comment: Glad I help you. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can position the badges absolutely and just add `position: relative;` to the `<li>` elements. This together with fiddling with the top and right css attributes solves the problem.

This is the part of css I modified:

```
.notification-bar> li {
  position: relative; // Add this so the badges keep inside the li element
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 19px 20px 15px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.notification-bar>li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.7);
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.pulse-badge {
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.87);
  ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-height: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1.3rem;
  top: 1em; // Edit this a little to place it where you wanted
  right: 1.1em; // Add this so the badges will be aligned on the right side of the icon
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, .051);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.33, 0, 1);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mz2m2qc1/1/

Comment: Thank you also for your solution. Works now for me . Thumbs up :)

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Nice to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you use margin instead of right position remove `margin` and use right position and every thing will be fine. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/febg4cuo/4/)

Comment: Works, but now are both badges one above the other

Comment: @PeymanEtedali  add display block on <a> tag and add position relative then it will work perfectly